# Do I need to renew my US tourist visa in my home country or in the country where I reside now temporarily?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-renewals

I have a Philippine ls passport and I want to renew my US tourist visa before it expires. Where can I get most likely approval: in my home country or where I currently reside with my spouse, South Africa (temporary resident visa only). Hoping for answers. Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends in part on how temporary your residence in South Africa is.  How long have you been there?  How long do you plan to stay there?  Do you want to visit the US before you leave South Africa?  (There's no benefit to applying for your next US visa before the current one expires; you may as well wait until the next time you actually plan to visit the US.)

Comment: @phoog : Thanks for the advice. I’ve been here for almost a year already and planning to stay until I get my PR visa. My plan to visit US would be next year. So it’s not true what I heard that it’s easier to apply for renewal before the visa actually expires? Thank you so much!

Comment: @user79057 I don't know for a fact that it's not true, but I cannot imagine any reason why it would be.  People often use the term "renewal" to describe a new visa, but in either case it is treated as a fresh application, and in both cases your travel history, presumably one of compliance, with your earlier visa will be taken into account.  There's no reason why a gap after the prior visa's expiration would have any ill effect.

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116579/do-i-need-to-renew-my-us-tourist-visa-in-my-home-country-or-in-the-country-where/116602#comment284614_116579), you write:

> I’ve been here for almost a year already and planning to stay until I get my PR visa.

Since your residence is temporary only in terms of the name of your legal status, you should apply for your new visa in South Africa.  Here's what the US State Department [has to say about it](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html):

> You should schedule an appointment for your visa interview at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. You may schedule your interview at another U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be aware that it may be more difficult to qualify for a visa outside of the country where you live.

You live in South Africa, so you should apply in South Africa.

Comment: Your comments directly go against your quote that says you CAN apply anywhere.  "Permanent" is a specific term when it comes to immigration that isn't necessarily relevant in cases like this.  eg, I've been a "temporary" resident of the country I live in for over 10 years. I very certainly "reside" there, despite not having permanent residence.

Comment: @Doc Which comment?  I echo the State department's language that uses "should," which is not the same as "must": user79057 *can* apply anywhere, as you say, but *should* apply in South Africa because the application will be most likely to succeed there.  The mention of the word "temporary" was intended to counter the possible line of reasoning that because residence is nominally "temporary" the application should be submitted in a different place.

Comment: @phoog Thanks again for your feedback. You made my decision making easier. I’ll apply for my renewal of US visa here in SA as this is where I live now with my husband. Actually, I got Relatives Visa which is under Temporary Resident Visa. This has expiration date so I would definitely renew my visa here before it expires.